# Add item in Listview is too slow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

My problem is that I need to add a lot of items to a Listview in WPF. In WinForms you'd just use the `BeginUpdate()` method, add everything, and finally use the `EndUpdate()` method.

So, how would I stop the drawing in a WPF Listview until every item is added and then draw everything in one go?

```
 foreach (FilePaths filePath in directoryPath.GetFilePaths())
 {
   GetFileListViewItem(filePath);
 }
```

In this `GetFileListViewItem` method, i add the item to listview.

```
private void GetFileListViewItem(FilePaths filePath)
{
        string ext = GetExtension(filePath.GetPath());
        string fileName = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath.GetPath());
        string type = "";
        if (ext != "")
        { 
            type =  ext.ToUpper().Substring(1) + " File";
        }
        else
        {
            type = "Unknown";
        }

        fileListView.Items.Add(new FileListItem
        {
            Name = fileName,
            Type = type
        });
 }
```

Comment: Code that you are using?

Comment: @ChrisBint - updated

Comment: But that does NOT draw one item at a time.  The UI is not refreshed until that call (and other calls) are complete.  Code behind is processed 100% before drawing the UI.  Now you are generating more UI change events than you need to but the UI is painted once.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and solved it by delay adding, i code a custom add with for example 500 millisecond delay,if i have any more adding in this time so i wait a next 500 millisecond.
this causes when you have too many adding items frequently so  just single render in your form will occur.

Answer (score 1):

I think, when dealing with WPF, you are better off getting away from the WinForms mentality of directly manipulating controls in code behind.  One of WPFs biggest strengths is its data binding capabilities.

The `ListView` control (anything that inherits from `ItemsControl` it appears) implements UI virtualization.  From this link: [WPF: Data Virtualization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)

> When a WPF ItemsControl is bound to a large collection data source, with UI virtualization enabled, the control will only create visual containers for the items that are actually visible (plus a few above and below). This is typically only a small fraction of the entire collection. When the user scrolls, new visual containers are created as items become visible, and old containers are disposed when items are no longer visible. When container recycling is enabled, it will reuse visual containers instead of creating and disposing, avoiding the object instantiation and garbage collection overheads.
>   
>   
>   UI virtualization means that controls can be bound to large collections without incurring a large memory footprint due to visual containers. There is, however, a potentially large memory footprint due to the actual data objects in the collection.

However, based on the answer to this [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8727eb5b-03ae-449d-a7f0-3f0e71cee58f/listview-ui-virtualization?forum=wpf), it appears that virtualization only kicks in when you data bind the `ItemsSource` property to a collection.  So it would seem that directly adding items to the `ListView`, as you are doing, is preventing virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing code inside a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with a priority below DispatcherPriority.Render

This should add all items before render.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, (Action)delegate
{
     GetFileListViewItem(filePath);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DataBinding
Bind the DataSource of the ListVies to MyFileListItem
Magical speed will happen
I think adding direct breaks virtualization
It does paint once but you are generating muliple UI change notifications
This will just be one data binding

If you are going to add and remove then use an ObservableCollection
If values will change in a FileListItem then you need to implement iNotifyProperty changed

```
private List<FileListItem> myFileListItems;   
public List<FileListItem> MyFileListItems 
{
    get 
    {  
       if (myFileListItems == null) 
       { 
           myFileLinstItems = new List<FileListItem>();
           foreach (FilePaths filePath in directoryPath.GetFilePaths())
           {
               string ext = GetExtension(filePath.GetPath());
               if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ext)
                  ext = "Unknown";
               else 
                  ext = ext.ToUpper().Substring(1) + " File";
               myFileListItems.Add(new FileListItem
                                   {
                                      Name = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath.GetPath());,
                                      Type = ext
                                   });
           }
       }  
       return myFileListItems;
    }
 }
```